# Mailchimp is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, mailchimp

ERROR is coming that mailchimp is not a constructor I am using vanilla js and working with mailchimp api and their documentaition.

I am making a project to help them to find a job I am working on the backend and I have added a newsletter in my website (currently in development) and I am using mailchimp and I was following their [documentation](https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/guides/quick-start) I am trying to Add email to Mailchimp audience and to send them some promotional and helpful emails and I tried to call the api but when I say

```
npm start
```

**It just throws a error**

> const mailchimp = new Mailchimp('API_KEY_IS_HERE');
>
> TypeError: Mailchimp is not a constructor

**and the CODE IS**

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const { Mailchimp } = require('@mailchimp/mailchimp_marketing');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

// Set up Mailchimp
const mailchimp = new Mailchimp('API_KEY_IS_HERE');

// Add email to Mailchimp audience
app.post('/api/subscribe', async (req, res) => {
  const { email } = req.body;

  try {
    const response = await mailchimp.lists.addListMember('AUDIENCE_KEY_IS_HERE', {
      email_address: email,
      status: 'subscribed',
    });

    res.json({ message: 'Successfully subscribed!' });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error subscribing:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Subscription failed.' });
  }
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@mailchimp/mailchimp_marketing": "^3.0.80",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.1"
  }
}
```

WHAT SHOULD I DO HERE?

Answer (score 0):

here's an example from Mailchimp's github page

```js
const mailchimp = require('@mailchimp/mailchimp_marketing');

mailchimp.setConfig({
  apiKey: 'YOUR_API_KEY',
  server: 'YOUR_SERVER_PREFIX',
});

async function callPing() {
  const response = await mailchimp.ping.get();
  console.log(response);
}

callPing();
```

as you can see they set it up with `setConfig` method

Comment: I have done this but I want to connect with the frontend also so I have to use express, and as I said this is the first piece of code in documentation but I want it to be connected with frontend also.

Comment: And if there is a way to connect by not using express please elaborate